# What to use to make a cloud-powered app

Tags: php, android

I've made an android app that let you save some data locally (for example: photos). Now i would like to create a web service that will automatically backup the data and later let the user to check them on a web application (eventually coded with PHP).

I know PHP for server side, and some python. Should i create a Rest-full api with php using a cms like described [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/) or should i use Google Cloud Platform? Which is more convenient?

The application should:

- Authenticate the user,
- Automatically backup the data,
- Let the user
  access the data on a web application

Answer (score 1):

Personally I find Parse to be really useful, powerful and affordable. In the scope of developing apps for local businesses we still haven't paid a dime and it has saved us a ton of development time. www.parse.com